# How to get stats from combined aggregated bin data in AWS Cloudwatch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have some AWS CloudWatch logs which output values every 5 seconds. I'd like to get the max over a rolling 10 minute interval and then get the average value per day based on that. Using the CloudWatch Logs Insights [QuerySyntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) I cannot seem to get the result of the first `bin` aggregation to use in the subsequent `bin`. I tried:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @LogStream like /mylog/
| parse @message '*' as threadCount
| stats max(threadCount) by bin(600s) as maxThreadCount
| stats avg(maxThreadCount) by bin(24h) as avgThreadCount
```

But the query syntax is invalid for multiple `stats` functions. Combining the last two lines into one like:

```
| stats avg(max(threadCount) by bin(600s)) by bin(24h) as threadCountAvg
```

Also is invalid. I can't seem to find much in the AWS logs. Am I out of luck? Anyone know a trick?

Comment: Ever found an answer for this? I am looking to do something similar.

Comment: No I spent an hour or so looking into but moved on.

Comment: Understandable. Thanks for the reply, though...